# PHP: trouble displaying contents of text files when using glob function

Tags: php, sorting, glob, readfile

For a photo journal, I have a PHP file that automatically pulls images and videos from a folder. Now I'd like it to automatically display the contents of txt files too, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

This is the code that works for images and videos:

```
$files = glob("images/*.*");
rsort($files);
for ($i = 0;$i < count($files);$i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    $supported_file = array(
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'png',
        'mp4',
    );
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
        
        if ($ext == 'mp4') {
            echo '<video width="900" controls loop> <source src="' . $image . '" type="video/mp4"/>'; 
            echo '</video>'."<br /> <br />";
        }

        else {
            echo '<img src="' . $image . '" width="900" />'."<br /> <br />";
        }
        
    } else {
        continue;
    }
    }
```

I tried adding 'txt' to the supported_file list and then this code after the second 'if':

```
    else ($ext == 'txt') {
        echo readfile( "' . $image . '");   
}
```

But it breaks the page. I've searched for help on displaying the contents of text files, but haven't seen anything on how to do it when using a glob function.

Any ideas?

Comment: "but it breaks the page" - the reason is explained in your log files - find out where they are and check them. It would also be reported in you run `php -l yourscript.php`

Comment: Thanks @symcbean. I get a syntax error 'unexpected token' on the line "echo readfile", which is exactly the line I've been wrestling with. I've tried changing it to include a 'src' command (as the echo commands for video and photos have) but I haven't found one that works with txt files.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (with some outside help)!

A text file command that works is:

```
 elseif ($ext === 'txt') {
        echo '<pre>' . file_get_contents($image) . '</pre>' . "<br />";
    }
```

The "pre" as I understand it, does two things: 1) allows formatting (paragraph breaks and html markup) from the original text file to be displayed on the page after the contents are "got"; and 2) acts as a tag for css styling, which is helpful for making the text do what you want on the page.

There were a few other changes to the whole script, so I'll post it all here in case anyone is curious or has any comments.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$files = glob("images/*.*");
rsort($files);
for ($i = 0;$i < count($files);$i++) {
   $image = $files[$i];
   $supported_file = array(
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'png',
    'mp4',
    'txt',
);
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
# echo "<pre>". $image . "</pre>";
if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
    
    if ($ext == 'mp4') {
        echo '<video width="900" controls loop> <source src="' . $image . '" type="video/mp4"/>'; 
        echo '</video>'."<br /> <br />";
    }

  elseif ($ext === 'txt') {
        echo '<pre>' . file_get_contents($image) . '</pre>' . "<br />";
    }

    else {
        echo '<img src="' . $image . '" width="900" />'."<br /> <br />";
    }
    
} else {
    continue;
}
}
?>
```